# Problema ao testar app no emulador

Tags: android, ionic, apache-cordova

Estou tendo o seguinte problema:

Quando eu executo o seguinte comando no ionic 6.6.0

```
 ionic cordova run android -l
```

O projeto compila, mas quando vai tentar emular traz os seguintes problemas:

```
 [cordova]  
 [cordova] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
 [cordova]  
 [cordova] * What went wrong: 
 [cordova] Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'. 
 [cordova] > Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store "/home/brito/.android/debug.keystore": keystore password was incorrect 
 [cordova]  
 [cordova] * Try: 
 [cordova]  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full
 insights. 
 [cordova]  
 [cordova] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org 
 [cordova]  
 [cordova] BUILD FAILED in 10s
 [cordova] /home/brito/Documentos/Projetos/raynero/raynero-app/platforms/android/gradlew:     Command failed with exit code 1 Error output: 
 [cordova] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. 
 [cordova]  
 [cordova] * What went wrong:
 [cordova] Execution failed for task ':app:packageDebug'. 
 [cordova] > Failed to read key AndroidDebugKey from store     "/home/brito/.android/debug.keystore": keystore password was incorrect
 [cordova]  
 [cordova] * Try: [cordova] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights. 
 [cordova]  
 [cordova] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org 
 [cordova]  
 [cordova] BUILD FAILED in 10s 
 [ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

 cordova build android exited with exit code 1.

Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information
```

Já executei o seguinte comando e nada de funcionar:

```
         keytool -genkey -alias raynero -keystore ./keystore/debug.keystore
```

Tentei também copiar o arquivo `debug.keystore` gerado para a pasta `~/.android` e também não funcionou

Onde direciono o debug.keystore para a minha pasta keytore dentro do projeto?

O que mais devo fazer para que ao rodar o `ionic cordova run android -l` possa reconhecer o debug.keystore da minha pasta específica?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver da seguinte forma:

Na minha pasta `~/.android`, apaguei tudo o que tinha `debug.keystore` e `debug.keystore.lock` e advinha?

It works

Espero que possa ajudar alguém algum dia